# JavaScript MVC Framework + raphaelJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, raphael, javascript-framework

I'm trying to make an app that has a client MVC architecture, but in addition to HTML templates, it has SVG elements as the View (I use raphael to manage this).

Is there any JavaScript MVC framework that works well with raphaelJS as the View?

In the case that there isn't, are there any suggested frameworks that could work well with it?

Answer (score 6):

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) is a simply MVC framework, it not limit which template engine to use but give the choice to yourself.

In backbone render function, it always generate HTML code from some JSON data like this:

```
render: function () {
    // use underscore as template engine
    this.el.innerHTML = _.template(TMPL_STRING).render(JSON_DATA);
}
```

Use RaphaelJS here is very easy:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.paper = Raphael(this.el, width, height);
},
render: function () {
    // use this.paper to render svg here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencha makes ExtJS which is an MVC JS Framework - though some would argue that is not true.  Since Sencha bought/absorbed Raphael I'm imagining a time in the near future where the two libraries are optimized to work together and maybe even merge.